# How to show the full (not truncated) "CREATED BY" commands in "docker history" output?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

How can I show the full command in the third column (CREATED BY) in the `docker history` output?

```
$ $ docker history python
IMAGE          CREATED       CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
69ee9abe2bda   5 weeks ago   CMD ["python3"]                                 0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      5 weeks ago   RUN /bin/sh -c set -eux;   wget -O get-pip.p…   10MB      buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      5 weeks ago   ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256=22b849a10f86f5ddf7…   0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
...
```

The `CREATED BY` is truncating/abbreviating the commands which makes it hard to reconstruct the original Dockerfile. How do I get the full `CREATED BY` commands?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use the `docker history --no-trunc` option to show the full command.

Answer (score 18):

I needed to see the full build history without truncated build steps in a tabular format for debugging purposes.  The Docker Docs examples are often incomplete (or non-existent).  The accepted answer by @Alassane_Hdiaye can work, but throws an error if used in the wrong place.  After a couple tries, I got the GoLang template table formatter to produce the result I needed.

The Docker GoLang template `--format` option works with `docker history`, but must be entered AFTER `--format`, because it modifies `--format`, NOT `docker history`.  The `docker history` command takes only 1 argument.  The `--format` option changes the output of `docker history`, and `--no-trunc` modifies the `--format` option.

The command sequence must be

`docker history <image-id> --format <GoLang template spec> --no-trunc`

The `--no-trunc` option follows `--format` on the command line, because it modifies the `--format` option.

---

So for the fully history in a tabular format:

```
docker history <image-id> --format "table{{.ID}}, {{.CreatedBy}}" --no-trunc
```

---

The output is messy, because Dockerfile RUN commands can wrap many lines.

So pipe the result to a CSV file and open it in Excel (for lack of a better table viewer).

```
docker history <image-id> --format "table{{.ID}}, {{.CreatedBy}}" --no-trunc > image-id-history.csv
```

So now I can see complete build instructions in Excel without truncation.

---

As a side note, `Docker history` does not output RUN and other dockerfile build keywords, but these can be inferred.  But at least full commands from the complete history are available.

Comment: This is simply not true. I just ran the command `docker history --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}}: {{.CreatedBy}}" <image_name>` and got the desired output, without any problem. The `--no-trunc` option could be placed *before* the `--format` as well

Comment: Might've been true with the past versions of docker but now can confirm what @BakItzik said. Though valuable answer nonetheless since bare `--no-trunc` is unreadable due to the whitespace overflow.